# How to force Access-Control-Allow-Origin in an IIS hosted C# webservice

Tags: c#, angular, iis, cors

I have a .net webservice hosted in IIS 10. I'm trying to get data from the webserver from an angular frontend.

I have Access-Control-Allow-Origin enabled in IIS:
[image]

I also have customHeaders enabled in my Web.Conf:

[image]

When I attempt to access the webservice from an angular front end I recieve this error:

[image]

I'm using HttpClient from @angular/common/http and have tried several variations on requests but still no luck. Here is my latest failed request

```
public GetSlippage(tradeGroup: string, start: string, end: string, period: string, premiumFilter: number): Observable<SlippageContainer> {
    let url: string = `${this._slippageUrl}/${tradeGroup}`;
    let queryParams: HttpParams = new HttpParams()
    .set('start', start)
    .set('end', end)
    .set('period', 'none')
    .set('premium', String(premiumFilter));

    let heads: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    heads = heads.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    heads = heads.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    console.log(`Sent Slippage Request ${start} ${end}`);
    return this._httpClient.get<SlippageContainer>(url, { headers: heads, params: queryParams });
}
```

For some reason the requests work when I use `http://<serverName>:port/endpoint`
but not `http://<serverName.domainName.local:port/endpoint`. Ultimately I want to be able to use fully qualified domain names in the urls.

Comment: those are response headers.

Comment: @DanielA.White can you clarify? I have GET listed in the methods in IIS and also in the Allow-Methods in the web.conf.

Answer (score 0):

you need to allow CORS in your asp.net app.
In ConfigureServices add:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader();
}));
```

and in Configure add:

```
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
```

you can make more restrictive policies by specifying methods, headers and origins.